# Установка Ubuntu server на VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Пытаюсь установить Ubuntu server 20.04 на виртуальную машину (VirtualBox). При установки выводит такие надписи и зависает на этом месте. В чем проблема и как ее исправить, подскажите пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. файл проверяли после скачивания? 2. отключите все иные блочные устройства в этой вирт. машине. 3. если ничего не поможет — вам [сюда](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: Поддерживаю автора выше, попробуйте скачать новый дисрибутив, если установка происходит с носителя то смените и носитель на всякий, уберите лишние устройства и при настройке установки ничего не меняйте с умолчания и если не пойдет наоборот отключите максимум ненужностей